# Arithmetic operation in condition expression DynamoDb Using the AWS SDK for Java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb Table and I want to do a conditional update operation on that using aws sdk java library. I have the table with hashkey named as "Id" and sortkey named as "Sk"  . I have 5 other fields in the table and i have to update 2 fields based on the condition on the remaining fields. The condition is "total_record_count = record_passed + records_failed" , where total_record_count, record_passed and records_failed are the fields in the table. 
Below is the code

```
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(amazonDynamoDB);
        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("ciw_ocrResponse_upload");

        Map<String, String> expressionAttributeNames = new HashMap<String, String>();
        expressionAttributeNames.put("#updatedAt", "updatedAt");
        expressionAttributeNames.put("#statusOfTracker","statusOfTracker");

        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Map<String, Object> eav = new HashMap<>();
        eav.put(":val1", value);
        eav.put(":val2", timestamp.getTime());


        UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("Id", requestId, "Sk", sortKey)
                .withUpdateExpression("set #updatedAt = :val2, #statusOfTracker = :val1")
                .withValueMap(eav)
                .withNameMap(expressionAttributeNames)
                .withConditionExpression(" total_record_count = record_passed + records_failed")
                .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.UPDATED_NEW);

        table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
```

```
I am getting the error as Invalid ConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: "+", near: "record_passed + records_failed"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Syntax) this arithmetic operation is not supported.

Workaround is to create a `total_record_count` field which you need to calculate and add on every new item created. Also to add it to all existing items.

Comment: If I calculate first ( i.e if I read the value from the database first) and then update, the race condition will happen as I have 8 threads which are simultaneously reading and updating the values in the database if the given condition " total_record_count = record_passed + records_failed" satisfies.      How to deal with this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to the concurrency issue @sumitmamtani?